# How can I load an image with its alpha channel with skimage?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, scikit-image

I am using an Anaconda distribution of Python with stuff like `numpy`, `scipy`, and `scikit-image`.

When I call:

```
from skimage import io
img = io.imread('myimage.png')
```

It ignores my alpha channel and returns the image as an array with shape `(W, H, 3)` instead of `(W, H, 4)`. How can I get the alpha channel of the image?

Comment: If your file is an *indexed* PNG with an alpha channel, and if the backend used by skimage is pillow, there is a bug (fixed in December) that can cause the alpha channel to be lost: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/1790

Comment: I am not sure the PNG type my file has. How do I tell whether the PNG is an *indexed* png?

Comment: I get those sprites from pages like this http://www.famitsu.com/freegame/tool/chibi/index1.html (cannot tell anymore about the generation process since it is not made from html canvas but server-side code)

Comment: On my Mac, I open the file (i.e. from a terminal, `open myimage.png`, or double-click in Finder), which views the file with Preview.  In Preview, use Tools/Show Inspector to open a window containing information about the image.  In Linux, you could use something like `pnginfo`, or an image editor might show the information.  I don't use Windows much, so I don't know what would be the simplest option there.

Comment: @StepanYakovenko, I see you added a bounty to this question.  Which versions of `scikit-image` and `pillow` do you have installed?  I just tried reading two different PNG files that have alpha channels (one indexed, the other not), using scikit-image 0.15.0 and pillow 6.0.0.  The image, including the alpha channel, was read correctly in both cases.

Comment: I have up-voted this by mistake. Put your investigation as an answer and I'll give you a bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Some PNG images include alpha channel from the go.
So just simple

```
from skimage import io
img = io.imread('myimage.png')
```

returns `(W, H, 4)`.

Some times, with PNG or JPG images you don't get aRGB, you can try

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('myimage.png')
img_a = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
print(img_a.shape) #(W, H, 4)
```

As in both `skimage.io` and `cv2.imread` return a `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` you can use both interchangeably for any operation.